# How to fill arrays recursively with random numbers and print them recursively?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, recursion

It's possible to fill arrays with random numbers recursively (Python). It's a problem from a Python-programming course. Now I'm trying to find out how to do it. Could anybody give me a tip on how to do it, please? I'm realy blocked right now for a while. I have no problems with recursions but this one is a quite difficult one I think.

The following is the minimized scope of this problem. The first two functions: `fillArrRecursively(arr, max, seed)` and `displayArrRecursively(arr)` **(and I may not add/use other parameters)** are the functions I need and the ones that must be re-defined. I have already made a simple iterative approach, it works, but this is not the solution of the problem.

```
def fillArrRecursively(arr, max, seed):
    ### This is the iterative approach, but I need the recursive one
    random.seed(seed)
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        arr[i] = random.randint(0, max)

def displayArrRecursively(arr):
    ### This again is the iterative approach, but I need the recursive one
    for item in arr:
        print('{0:>5}'.format(item), end='')

def recursiveApproach(seed, length, max):
    ### This function may not be edited
    arr = [0] * length
    fillArrRecursively(arr, max, seed)
    displayArrRecursively(arr)

def main():
    ### This function may not be edited
    length = 100
    max = 20
    seed = random.randint(1, 1000000)
    recursiveApproach(seed, length, max)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it really is required to:

- have the parameters of `fillArrRecursively` fixed to `arr, max, seed`, and
- the recursion has to happen on `fillArrRecursively` itself, and not a nested function that is defined within it

... then the problem is what you will modify in each recursive call so you know which element to fill and when to end. Normally you would pass an index into the recursion tree.

Now there is a window of opportunity, since the *seed* argument should only be used once: it makes no sense to call the `random.seed` function multiple times with the same argument. So, this argument could get another use in the recursive calls, and take the meaning of the index. As apparently the seed is passed as a positive number, one could agree that a negative value for *seed* denotes an index. This kind of re-use of an argument obscures code, and is not advisable, but given the constraints, I think this is the way to go:

```
def fillArrRecursively(arr, max, seed):
    if seed > 0:
        random.seed(seed)
        seed = -len(arr)
    if seed < 0:
        arr[-seed-1] = random.randint(0, max)
        fillArrRecursively(arr, max, seed+1)
```

For the display part it is easier, as you don't need to modify the array, and so you can slice the array as you go:

```
def displayArrRecursively(arr):
    if len(arr):
        print('{0:>5}'.format(arr[0]), end='')
        displayArrRecursively(arr[1:])
    print()
```

Comment: You're welcome ;-) In fact, I thought of another solution, but have to abandon that. this is it.

Comment: Woah, you beat me to it. I was slow.

Comment: I'm sorry Gurupad Mamadapur. this is the life on stackoverflow. I just looked at the code of trincot and understood instantly what he did.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this was tricky and useless.

Anyways, what I did was use the `seed` parameter as an index to add random elements.

`random.seed(seed) # This statement is executed only once, as it should be`

```
def fillArrRecursively(arr, _max, seed):
    if seed>0:
        random.seed(seed)
        seed=0

    if abs(seed)<len(arr):
        arr[abs(seed)]=r(0,_max)
        return fillArrRecursively(arr,_max,seed-1)


def display(arr):
    if not arr:
        return ""
    if arr:
        print (arr[0]+1)
        return display(arr[1:])
```

It is guaranteed from your un-editable code that seed will always be greater that 0. Use that as an advantage to turn the seed parameter into an index variable with a negative value. But, be cautious while indexing, use the `abs(seed)` to get the absolute value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `fillArrRecursively` does not have the parameter `length`. It only has `arr`, `max` and `seed`. If you remove the parameter `seed` you only have two remaining parameters.

Comment: And I may not edit the function `recursionApproach`. I just must edit the function `fillArrRecursively(arr, max, seed)` to make it work recursively.

Comment: So, if you do not want to use the `seed` parameter, just to show a tip on how to solve this problem, the function becomes then like `fillArrRecursively(arr, max)`.

Comment: @LowLevel Oh okay, I'll make those changes, gimme some time.

Comment: @LowLevel I made the changes, but I was slow, hope it helps in some way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing that the list has already been created and has predefined length.

```
def FillList(data, length, max, seed, i=0):
    if i >= length: return data

    # move seeding outta here
    data[i] = random.randint(0, max)

    return FillList(data, length, max, seed, i + 1)
```

Let's move on to outputting the list:

```
def Output(data):
    if data:
        print(data[0], end='')
        Output(data[1:])
```

Please note that this code might be inefficient as `data[1:]` creates a copy of the list starting with index `1`.

Comment: I really may not add/use other parameters than `(arr, max, seed)`

Comment: `data[1:]` will not work in the first function, as it makes a copy of the data, and so you'll not see the result of the recursive call unless you deal with that specifically.

Comment: @trincot, this is why I added the warning in bold

Comment: This returns the list with all elements set to the seed value.

Comment: @GurupadMamadapur, it does, indeed. The question is how to do the recursion, not how to initialize random number generation:) The continuous calls to `seed` are the source of the issue.

Comment: Just note that in the OP's iterative version, `random.seed` was called only once.